Change Python Version
I recently had to revert back from Python312 to Python 310 in another project/development environment. But that has apparently broken LiClipse. When I bring up run configurations, they all give the path to Python312 and I see no way to change that to Python310. My environment variable is set to where Python is installed: (BTW my other development environment, VSCode, sees this just fine)
PYTHONPATH=C:\Users<user>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310
In fiddling around I removed the hidden files (.project and .metadata) in my old project folder in an effort to start from scratch. But now I can't even create a project. The entire project tree shows up in the IDE, but it is apparently not a 'project'. The options in the Project menu do not seem to help.
I try to create a run configuration, but the only field I have access to is at the top where I name the configuration. Everything else is inaccessible, so I can not set the Project, the Main Module, or the information that used to be in the large text box indicating the paths to Python. There has to be someplace that LiClipse reads the path to Python, but I sure can not find it!
This is a very old project I have been working on for years, but now I cant run it? Why is this so hard?

Never ever delete your .metadata folder as this can wreck your workspace and cause data loss. Please help prevent this hoax from spreading further by not even mentioning it in your question. In general, do not delete files you do not know about. "but it is apparently not a 'project'" - yes, of course, you deleted the .project file. If you have a backup, restore the files. Otherwise, you must import the project.

Just restored the .metadata. Then tried to 'import' a project. I am now presented with quite a list of options. Under General I picked 'File System', but that did not seem right, it seemed like it was about to copy from the folder I picked into another folder. So I picked 'Projects from folder or archive' and that seemed to go better. but now I do not see my file tree under the main folder (I have a src folder with most of peripheral .py files and under that a 'gui' folder that has the main program file in it.

(continued...) None of those are visible in the file tree on the left, all I see is 'PyDev package explorer' that does not expand. One encouraging sign is that a window popped up asking for my path to Python, and it did find the correct Python 310 set of folders. I opened the main program file, but it did not run, and I could not complete the Run configuration.

@CaseyB66 the proper thing to do here is configure PyDev (which is the Python plugin used in LiClipse) by pointing it to the proper python interpreter.
Please read the related getting started for details on how to configure the interpreter used by PyDev: https://www.pydev.org/manual_101_interpreter.html.
